# System.Data.sqlClient will only create default database on server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Background:

I am using sql statements to create a Temp database on a server which will store data until it is needed further by my client program.

Problem:

My sql statement to create the database works properly and creates the database with all the required specifications when run through Sql Management studio, on the other hand when my program executes the statement it only creates a database with the 'Default' settings except for the name.

Questions:

1. Why is this?
2. How can I make it create a database with my specifications

Sql statement:

> CREATE DATABASE Temp ON PRIMARY(
>          NAME = Temp
>          , FILENAME = 'C:\Temp.mdf'
>          , SIZE = 2MB
>          , FILEGROWTH = 10%)  LOG ON (
>          NAME = Temp_Log
>          , FILENAME = 'C:\Temp.ldf'
>          , SIZE = 1MB, MAXSIZE = 70MB
>          , FILEGROWTH = 10%)

Code:

```
public void AcuConvert()
        {
            using (DestD)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                DestD.Open();
                command.Connection = DestD;
                foreach (var item in Entity.SqlDestinationQueries.ToList())
                {
                    command.CommandText = item.Query; 
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();    //This is where the command is run
                }
                foreach (var item in Entity.SystemQueries.ToList())
                {
                    command.CommandText = item.Query.Replace("@Sys", SysD.Database);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                foreach (var item in Entity.InsertQueries.ToList())
                {
                    command.CommandText = item.Query.Replace("@Source", SourceD.Database); ;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler on the server and capturing the exact command executed against the server? That might give you a clue as to why it does not add the settings.

Comment: What settings are actually applied?

Comment: What is the connection string value and which user you're connecting in SSMS?

Comment: The user connecting has full rights to everything, the settings applied to the database upon creation through the above code has a logfile max size of 5mb and a default starting size of 10mb

Comment: I do the exact same thing in one of my applications - but using OleDB - and it works fine...

Comment: This looks like a SQL permissions issue.  Try using SSMS, log into the server using the same user credentials, open a new query window, and execute your code.

Comment: As stated in my question when run through SSMS it works fine, but not when implemented through my program, though I am running under full permissions

Comment: @jvanh1: in my SSMS your sql statement didn't even run saying `..The primary file must be at least 3 MB..`   I wonder how could you run it?  by the way which version of SQL Serer are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) instead of a raw SQL statement?

For example:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

...

// Connect to the default instance
Server server = new Server();
// Establish new database details
Database database = new Database(server, "MyTempDB");
// Add primary filegroup details
database.FileGroups.Add(new FileGroup(database, "PRIMARY"));

// Set Primary datafile properties
DataFile primaryFile = new DataFile(database.FileGroups["PRIMARY"],
    "MyTempDB_Data", "C:\\MyTempDB.mdf");
primaryFile.Size = 2048;   // Sizes are in KB
primaryFile.GrowthType = FileGrowthType.Percent;
primaryFile.Growth = 10;
// Add to the Primary filegroup
database.FileGroups["PRIMARY"].Files.Add(primaryFile);

// Define the log file
LogFile logfile = new LogFile(database, "MyTempDB_Log", "C:\\MyTempDB_Log.ldf");
logfile.Size = 1024;
logfile.GrowthType = FileGrowthType.Percent;
logfile.Growth = 10;
logfile.MaxSize = 70 * 1024;
// Add to the database
database.LogFiles.Add(logfile);

// Create
database.Create();
database.Refresh();
```

You can connect to the server with specific credentials, too, of course:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx

If, however, you're stuck with using text scripts to create your database, I'd ensure that your Initial Catalog is set correctly (i.e. to 'master') in your connection string and your user has the necessary permissions - CREATE DATABASE / CREATE ANY DATABASE / ALTER DATABASE. If this still doesn't give you any joy, try stripping out the rest of your C# code and run the create SQL independently of the other statements - it could be that there's a side-effect from a preceding query. Use [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to see exactly what's running as you add them back in.

**Edit:**

I tested your script against a local SQL Server instance (2012 SqlLocalDB) via a small C# program using SqlClient and it ran just fine after changing the file paths to ones I had write access to (root of C is protected by default). The only other amendment was that the Primary size had to start at 3MB or more. Any smaller and the default tables could not be created. This may be another avenue of investigation for you to explore.

Comment: How big the primary data file has to be depends on the model database since it is created as a copy of the model db. You can shrink the model db to allow for smaller initial db sizes.

Comment: @TToni - that's interesting, I never knew you could shrink model. The 3MB default primary size was for a new SqlLocalDB install. I believe 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2 have a 2MB default, but I don't know what version the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative option could be to use the Process class to run the sqlcmd.exe
Eg.
var process = Process.Start(WORKING_PATH, argument);

%WORKING_PATH% being "C:\tools\sql\sqlcmd.exe"

%argument% being  "C:\scripts\Create.sql"

I use this strategy to dump test data into test environments when bootstrapping acceptance test fixtures.

Cheers